# An error occurred while loading the project properties editor

Tags: migration, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

While migrating the from .NET 4.8 to .NET Core 8, I encountered an error while opening the properties tab:

> System.ArgumentException: Expected 1 values for property Build::DefineConstants, but got 0. The property page may not be defined for all configurations.
>
> Parameter name: values
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property.Update(ImmutableArray`1 values)   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property..ctor(PropertyMetadata metadata, ImmutableArray`1 values, PropertyContext context, ImmutableHashSet`1 varyByDimensions)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContextFactoryBase.ToProperty(IUIPropertySnapshot property, Page page, Category category, Int32 order, PropertyContext propertyContext, IPropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.g__CreateProperties|14_5(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.g__ProcessInitialData|14_1(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )

I have been trying to migrate the existing .NET 4.8 application to .NET Core 8.

I have changed the existing GUID in the `.csproj` file, but I still encounter that issue.

Along with that, I have tried to check and uncheck the box from debug folder